# Is 'I want a manager who is open, and willing, to challenge' objectionable?

Tags: grammar

I think it's probably clear what the sentence means, but it jars a little with me because it feels like the word 'to' needs to be interpreted in two senses. Is it just me?

Comment: I don't think it's at all clear what the sentence means. Does the writer intend to challenge an open, willing manager? ("I want a sandwich that is open, and delicious, to eat.")  Or does he expect the manager to do the challenging ("I want a dinner guest who is hungry, and willing, to eat.")

Comment: I'd get rid of those two commas.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want a manager who is both up for a challenge and willing to challenge other people or things.  It's not "to" that's the problem, it's that "challenge" needs to function as a noun in one case and as a verb in the other.  Here are a couple of suggestions:

"I want a manager who is willing to challenge others and be challenged in return."

"I want a manager who is open to new challenges, and willing to challenge others."

Venturing afield from the topic of English usage, I also invite you to raise your expectations for your new manager; "open" and "willing" are not high bars.  Consider "excited," "eager," and "passionate."

Answer (score 1):

It's not just you.  This rhetorical device is called *syllepsis*, in which a single word (here *to*) stands in different grammatical relationship to two parts of the sentence.  Your desire is

> A manager who is open **to** [a] challenge from others and willing
>   **to** challenge others

The first *to* is a preposition governing the object *challenge*, and the second *to* is part of the infinitive *to challenge*.

Your challenge (if I may be permitted the use) is write the sentence in such a way that it doesn't mislead your reader into thinking that you want

> a manager who is open [minded] and willing to challenge others

and that doesn't mislead your reader into expecting a third item in a list:

> a manager who is open, willing to challenge, and rewards performance

I suggest

> I want a manager who is open (and willing) to challenge.